# How to get a search ranking based on multiple factors in sphinx?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, search-engine, sphinx

Hello stackoverflow folks,

We got a Rails project which is growing and growing and we now get first performance problems on the search, because we don't know how to utilize sphinx properly for our needs. 
We have search queries like "Java PHP Software developer". Our problem is now the ranking should work with multiple things.

As search fields we have tag list, description and title.
If one of the terms is inside of one of the fields it should get for example 2 points. More Points if its in more fields, but not multiple points if it is in the same field more than once.
Next Problem is I have a big file with synonyms for which should also be checked. It looks like this:

```
Java > Java
Java-EE > Java
...
```

So if Java-EE is found it should get some points too but with a penalty for being a synonym.

Maximum amount of points would be 5 as in 5 stars which get displayed.
Any speedy solution would be nice because at the moment it's done in plain ruby and it gets slow, because we cant rank properly in sphinx.

If there is a solution with another search engine that would also be very nice, as it could be changed.

Thanks in advance for all efforts. All spelling corrections and questions to clear the question are welcome.

Answer (score 2):

Most of the performance issues can be solved by changing the way you use sphinx. First you need to address how you index the data in sphinx. Doing some processing during while indexing will make the search quicker and the results more relevant. Second, tackle the search terms and last but not least, decide on the ranking algorithm to use.

I am going to use the "title" field as an example, but the logic can be replicated for all fields.

**Indexing**

Add two fields to sphinx ("title" and "title_synonyms"). For each record in the database do the following :-

- Perform a DISTINCT on the words to remove duplicates ("Ruby Developer / Java Developer" will become "Ruby Developer / Java". This will stop records from getting two scores for duplicates when searching. This goes in to "title"
- Take the DISTINCT title from above and REPLACE all the words with their expanded synonym equivalents. I would suggest putting the synonyms in the DB to make the expansion easier. The text would then become "Ruby Developer / Java-EE". Each word must be replaced with all the synonyms. If Java has two synonyms, they both must be in the field. This goes into "title_synonyms"

**Searching**

Because there are now two fields in sphinx we can give them each a different weight; "title" can get a weight of "10" and "title_synonyms" a weight of "3". That means a record has to match 4 synonyms before it ranks higher than one with the original title. You can play around with the weights to suit your needs.

Lets assume a user was searching for "Java Developer". For the search phrase do the following :-

- Remove duplicate words
- Get synonyms for each word in the search phrase
- Set Matching Mode in Sphinx to SPH_MATCH_EXTENDED

The above rules will mean the search in sphinx looks like this :-

@title "Java Developer" | @title_synonyms "Java-EE"

If you want to rank exact matches higher than lexemes, the search query would look like this :-

@title ("Java Developer" | "=Java =Developer") | @title_synonyms ("Java-EE" | "=Java-EE")

You will need to use SPH_RANK_PROXIMITY_BM25 or SPH_RANK_SPH04 to make this work properly though.

**Ranking**

You can try any of the built in ranking algorithms to see what the results look like. I recommend SPH_RANK_MATCHANY or SPH_RANK_WORDCOUNT as a start.

For Proximity and exact match ranking use SPH_RANK_PROXIMITY_BM25, SPH_RANK_SPH04 or SPH_RANK_EXPR where you can use your own algorithm.

**Conclusion**

You should now have a search that is both fast and accurate. Very little work has to be done by your Ruby application and most of the work is done inside sphinx (where it should be).

Hope this helps...

Comment: Thanks for your answer, we will try it out!

Answer (score 1):

This performance problem is an algorithm problem.

If you cannot express the problem in a way to utilize a backend tool, like sphinx or the database engine, then you are doing the processing in ruby, and that's easy to have a performance problem.

First, do as much as you can with sphinx (or whatever other search engine) and the database as you can.  The more pre-digested the data coming into ruby, the less you have to do in ruby code, and that will likely be faster, since databases have been highly optimized over the last half century.

So, for example, run sphinx on the key words.  Also run sphinx on the synonyms.  Limit all the answers to the top results, and merge the results.  That way your ruby code will be limited to the likely high results instead of having to consider the whole database of entries.

Once in ruby, the most important thing is to avoid high order algorithms, that is, make sure you are using a low order algorithm.

As you process your raw data, if you hold your top results in an array and try to sort or scan the array, you are going to have an N-squared order.  That is, your order will be the product of the number of raw entries and the number of elements you keep in your array.

The best algorithms for your problem are a priority queue implemented by a heap like container, or a b-tree.  Both have N-log-N order (N times the log of N), or the number of raw data records time the log of the number of items you will keep in your container.

A heap is a binary tree, where each node in the tree (not just the leaves but each node) has a rated record.  The nodes below each record all have lower ranks.  This is called the heap condition.

There are algorithms for adding elements, taking the top ranked element out, and replacing the lowest ranked element which maintain the heap condition.  Look up [binary heap](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_heap) in the wikipedia.

Let's say your site will display the top 100 ranked results.  Maintain a help where the root is the *lowest* ranked.  Populate the heap by adding the first 100 raw records you are processing.

Now for record 101 and after, compare its rank with the root.  If the new record is ranked higher, use the delete algorithm to reduce your heap to 99 nodes (which will remove the lowest ranked record in the heap) and add your new record to the heap.

Once you have gone through all your records, you will have the top 100 ranked results.  The heap delete algorithm will pull them out in reverse order.